# pgfplotstable adding vertical space between fractions

Tags: vertical-alignment, pgfplotstable, fractions

[image]

MWE

```
% stand-alone file to test writing a table in pgfplotstable
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow} % required
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\pgfplotstabletypeset
 [
  after row = \vspace{0.8mm},
  every head row/.style =
  {
    before row = \toprule,
    after row = \midrule,
  },
  every last row/.style =
  {
    after row = \bottomrule,
  },
  columns/x/.style =
  {
    column type = r,
    column name = $x$,
    frac,
  },
  columns/y/.style = 
  {
    column type = r,
    column name = ${y=\frac{2}{x}}$,
    frac,
  },
 ]
 {
     x    y
     -4   -0.5         % vertical space not added after this row
     -3   -0.66666666  % vert space added below here
     -2   -1
     -1   -2
     -0.5 -4
      0.5  4
      1    2
      2    1
      3    0.66666666
      4    0.5
 } % \pgfplotstabletypeset{} END
\end{document}
```

To display columns of fractions (with pgfplotstable, booktabs and multirows), I need to add vertical space between the rows so the fraction of the current row does not step on the fraction of the previous row. As shown in the MWE, I added

```
after row = {\vspace{0.8mm}},
```

to the options for \pgfplotstabletypeset, but it compiled by adding space to every row *after* row 1, not between rows 0 and 1. See image.

I added the usual arraystretch command (commented out in MWE) prior to \pgfplotstabletypeset, but it is outside my block, and since I have dozens of tables in this document, not all need to have the array stretch applied. Yes, I could put braces around the source text, but I hope there is something cleaner to add to the options that I missed.

Why is the space not added between rows 0 and 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pgfplotstable` allows you to specify the code for fractions via `frac TeX`. This can be used to add more vertical space where fractions appear e.g. by adding a vertical phantom.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow} % required
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\pgfplotstabletypeset
 [
  after row ={[0.3ex]}, %<use this instead of \vspace
  frac TeX=\vphantom{\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}}\frac,
  every head row/.style =
  {
    before row = \toprule,
    after row = \midrule,
  },
  every last row/.style =
  {
    after row = \bottomrule,
  },
  columns/x/.style =
  {
    column type = r,
    column name = $x$,
    frac,
  },
  columns/y/.style = 
  {
    column type = r,
    column name = ${y=\frac{2}{x}}$,
    frac,
  },
 ]
 {
     x  y
     -4 -0.5
     -3 -0.66666666 
     -2 -1
     -1 -2
     -0.5   -4
      0.5   4
      1 2
      2 1
      3 0.66666666
      4 0.5
 } % \pgfplotstabletypeset{} END
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to add `\hline` to each line?

Comment: @manooooh Yes, e.g. with `after row ={[0.3ex] \midrule},`.